# Change the From email address in a SharePoint 2013 Designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

Can we change the From email address in a SharePoint 2013 workflow which was developed in SharePoint Designer?

My email address is workflow@noreply, but it's different as we configured in outgoing email in central admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You cannot do this using the builtin "Send Email" function!